# jQuery UI 1.12.1 and jQuery 3

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make jQuery UI 1.12.1 work with jQuery 3.2.1. I gather from what I've read elsewhere, it should work, but the migration tool https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js is giving me warnings.

During the transition, I'm using uncompressed versions of jQuery UI and jQuery code.

Among the warnings I'm getting via the console:

1) `JQMIGRATE: jQuery.expr[":"] is now jQuery.expr.pseudos`

with respect to line 1249 in jquery-ui.js:

```
var data = $.extend( $.expr[ ":" ], {
```

2) `JQMIGRATE: jQuery.unique is deprecated, use jQuery.uniqueSort`

with respect to line 517 in jquery-ui.js:

```
current = $( $.unique( current.get().concat( options.element.get() ) ) );
```

I can give more examples if they are useful, but these warnings seem to be pretty directly to the point. I can't find any discussion of this online beyond the migration guide itself and this [list of warnings](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md). Any pointers? Might I be somehow using the wrong source for jQuery? Top of file identifies it as `jQuery UI - v1.12.1 - 2017-04-17`.

Comment: did you ever the replacement syntax for the first error?

Comment: No. I actually backed off of using jQueryUI 3, and just stuck with the latest version of jQueryUI 1, which meets our needs just fine and seems to be much better supported.

Comment: I am running to the exact same differences and more. 
The jQuery UI guys seem to have no problem, which I can not believe.
So I challenge them to give a working (CDN) example with:
   - jQuery 3.2.1
   - jQuery UI 1.xx.x
And optional:
   - Bootstrap 
   - Bootgrid

Comment: FWIW, I went on to the latest version of jQueryUI 2, which is fine. No way I am going to jQueryUI 3 again until I hear this has been addressed.

Comment: I've addressed this by fixing the migrate warnings. Here is the fixed jQuery UI release with version history of the corrections: https://github.com/DenisLabrecque/jQuery-UI-Fixed-for-3.5.1

Comment: Glad to hear it! This took so long that I'm no longer actively working on that project, but I'll pass this along to the people who are!